# JQuery Effects in Wordpress (non plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects

I am trying to change a Jquery behavour as well as adding one to a wordpress website.

The first thing I want to do is everytime I click on a page through the navigation I want the page to fade in and then make it seem the page has scrolled up. I can get the fase in to work but I can not get the page to scroll up or at least have the effect.

```
<script language="Javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    });
</script>
```

The second problem is that I have a image which shows the caption from the image when you role over it, I want it to fade in but scroll the caption up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        //move the image in pixel
        var move = -15;

        //zoom percentage, 1.2 =120%
        var zoom = 1.1;

        //On mouse over those thumbnail
        $('#client-rank .client-img').hover(function() {

            //Set the width and height according to the zoom percentage
            width = $('#client-rank .client-img').width() * zoom;
            height = $('#client-rank .client-img').height() * zoom;

            //Move and zoom the image
            $(this).find('#client-rank .client-img img').stop(false,true)
                .animate({
                    'width': width, 
                    'height': height, 
                    'top': move, 
                    'left': move
                }, {duration:200});

            //Display the caption
            $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeIn(200);

        },
        function() {
            //Reset the image
            $(this).find('img').stop(false,true)
                .animate({
                    'width': $('.item').width(), 
                    'height': $('.item').height(), 
                    'top': '0', 
                    'left': '0'
                }, {duration:100}); 

            //Hide the caption
            $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeOut(200);
        });

    });

</script>
```

[link ] `http://test-cocoonfxmedia.co.uk/elevate/clients!`

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. And you should also tell us what you have tried and what didn't work. For example, your first problem with having the page scroll up after fading in doesn't show any kind of code attempt at making that happen. Show us what you tried.

Comment: OK I am trying to get a scroll up effect to work on mouseover. 
<pre>    
    <script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#client-rank .client-img').mouseover(function() {          
        $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).slideUp('slow').fadeIn(500);
    });
    $('#client-rank .client-img').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('div.caption').stop(false,true).fadeOut(200);
    });
    });
    </script>
</pre>

The caption which is meant to slide up and fade in goes crazy and non stop.  Where as if I try this with scrollDown it works.